# VS 2010 Designer error when passing arguments to custom's control main function

Tags: c#, designer

I've written a custom control. I need a public function from the parent form, the control is in. So I pass the instance in the designer like this:

```
this.control= new mainform.control(this);
```

But the VS designer throws an error ans says:

> The variable 'control' is either undeclared or was never assigned.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a designer issue to me. Just do;

- Re-build your current solution
- Restart Visual Studio

As an alternative, you can create seperate assembly dll for custom controls.